# Ingress-nginx how to set externalIPs of nginx ingress to 1 ip externalIP only

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, k3s

i installed nginx ingress with the yaml file

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.2.0/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml
```

when deploy i can see that the endpoints/externalIPs by default are all the ip of my nodes
[image]

but i only want 1 externalIPs to be access able to my applications

i had tried bind-address(https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#bind-address) in a configuration file and applied it but it doesn't work, my ConfigMap file:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  bind-address: "192.168.30.16"
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
```

I tried `kubectl edit svc/ingress-nginx-controller -n ingress-nginx` to edit the svc adding externalIPs but it still doesn't work.

[image]

The only thing the nginx ingress document mentioned is https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/#external-ips but i tried editing the svc, after i changed, it was set to single IP, but later it re-add the IPs again. Seems like there an automatic update of external IPs mechanic in ingress-nginx?

Is there anyway to set nginx ingress externals ip to only 1 of the node ip? i'm running out of option for googling this. Hope someone can help me

Comment: Twice you say something "doesn't work." Can you add details around that part? Do you get an error? Does it appear to work without error but not actually give you the results you desire?

Comment: @Witt by doesn't work i mean the external IP of nginx service didn't get set to 1 IP. Both result doesn't show any errors from the logs

Answer (score 4):

> but I only want 1 external IPs to be access able to my applications

If you wish to "control" who can access your service(s) and from which ip/subnet/namesapce etc you should use `NetworkPolicy`

---

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/

> The entities that a Pod can communicate with are identified through a combination of the following 3 identifiers:
>
> 1. Other pods that are allowed (exception: a pod cannot block access to itself)
> 2. Namespaces that are allowed.
> 3. IP blocks (exception: traffic to and from the node where a Pod is running is always allowed, regardless of the IP address of the Pod or the node)
>
> When defining a pod- or namespace-based NetworkPolicy, you use a selector to specify what traffic is allowed to and from the Pod(s) that match the selector.
>
> Meanwhile, when IP-based NetworkPolicies are created, we define policies based on IP blocks (CIDR ranges).

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: test-network-policy
  namespace: default
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      role: db
  policyTypes:
    - Ingress
    - Egress
  ingress:
    - from:
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 172.17.0.0/16
            except:
              - 172.17.1.0/24
        - namespaceSelector:
            matchLabels:
              project: myproject
        - podSelector:
            matchLabels:
              role: frontend
      ports:
        - protocol: TCP
          port: 6379
  egress:
    - to:
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 10.0.0.0/24
      ports:
        - protocol: TCP
          port: 5978
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Dependent on whether there is a LoadBalancer implementation for your cluster that might as intended.

If you want to use a *specified node* use `type: NodePort`

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types

It might then also be useful to use a [nodeSelector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/) so you can control what node the nxinx controller gets scheduled to, for DNS reasons.